# Making my own crypting / decrypting - system

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I would like to make a simple crypting system.
Like when I type in "abc" the system will then type "123".
Should be able to make this as simple as possible, but I'm rather stuck.

I've tried, but I'm not sure how to make it call out "a" and then get "1".

Comment: No, I'm trying to make my own system, I don't want to use an already used system.  
Just want to know how to call out "a" if I type in "1".
Just a simple abc -> 123 system. From there I can try it out myself, and see how far it goes.   
Should be simple, or atleast it sounds simple, but not sure how to explain it, if this cannot be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all converting a string to alphanumeric string value is called [Data Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption). Using which you can encrypt and decrypt the data over the network(Generally used for secure data transmission). There various libraries and functions available for respective technological platforms.Such as

1. **Javascript** libraries : [Crypto js by Google.](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)
2. You should visit [mcrypt_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) & [mcrypt_decrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) for **php**